# Memory didn't back to the beginning after removing all subviews

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory

When I create a new project and run,all the code is:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
```

the memory is 53M:

[image]

Then I changed the code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i ++) {
        UITableView *tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
        tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
        tableView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
        [self.view addSubview:tableView];
    }
}

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    for (__strong UITableView *tableView in self.view.subviews) {
        [tableView removeFromSuperview];
        tableView = nil;
    }
}
```

**memory tendency:**

[image]

Before I taped the view,the memory is 117M,after I taped the view,all the subViews removed,the memory droped to 91M.

**Why 91M not 53M?**

NOTE:I use iPhone X simulator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start the memory profiler and see which objects are created in between. A UITableView is a pretty complicated object so it is possible that all kinds of stuff is cached or still around, but no way to know for sure.